# Indexing on column with few fixed values but values constitue to less than 25% of total rows

Tags: mysql, select, indexing

I have a field `table_name` in a table which can have only 20 different values. The total records in the table is about few tens of thousands of rows. If I do a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE table_name = 'adasd';
```

at most the returned records are 25% of the total rows. Mostly I get only 10% of the total records. Is there a scope to index the field `table_name` here? I hear that for indexes to work well it requires the values in that field to be unique or close to it. In my case, its not at all close to unique. But I also heard that if the returned rows are less in number compared to total number of rows, it makes a good case for indexing.

How should I go about this?

Comment: yes you can index that column

Comment: @SashiKant thanks. Can you post an answer with lil' more details? It will help ppl in future..

Comment: @N.B. excellent. that clarifies my incorrect understanding of indexing. Can you post it as answer?

Answer (score 3):

No they don't have to be unique to get a benefit from using indexes, however take some time to think about what the DBMS does when processing a query:

Full table scan - a sequential read through the data (i.e. very few seek operations)

Index lookup - a few seeks on the index to find the start of the selected data, then a sequential read (few seeks) to identify rows in the underlying table, then LOTS AND LOTS of seeks to fetch the rows from the table

Seeks are expensive.

(there is a secondary effect of full table scans in that they are more prone to flushing hot data out of the cache - but you should address the primary concern first).

In this case, it's unlikely that the DBMS would use the index if it were present, and even if it did, it would probably be slower than a full table scan. As a (very) rough rule of thumb, you're only going to get a benefit from an index if a predicate identifies less than around 5% of the rows (but it will vary depending on the relative size of the index and the data).

i.e. don't bother adding an index on this field alone.

I think you may benefit from spending some time thinking about why you need to run queries which return so many rows?

Comment: Why do you think these are different?

Comment: I am repeating my own comment, cardinality = `COUNT(DISTINCT(field))/COUNT(*)`, so higher the cardinality better the indexing. selectivity = `COUNT(*) WHERE field = 'xyz'/COUNT(*)`. So lower the selectivity better the indexing. My question is which should I depend on. Different because in my case selectivity is good (which is about 25% max) but cardinality is so poor (20/10000 which is about .002)

Comment: Almost, the higher the cardinality, the more likely the selectivity will be higher and hence the optimizer will choose indexes, but if the data is very skewed, then for some values of 'field' using an index will be more efective than a full table scan, but you'll need to add a hint. But the optimizer knows nothing about selectivity - it ignores the literal values in predicates. "Mostly I get only 10% of the total records" - implies there are dew /no cases where an index will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

## Revised Answer

I just learned that creating an index does not mean that MySQL will use it. Keeping that in mind, I will re-phrase my answer:

You should create an index on that column if (general or your own) practices suggest you to do so. MySQL will use heuristics; which include looking at the available indexes and their respective cardinality, to determine the best index to use or not to use an index at all.

Interesting reading about this topic [here](http://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/what-makes-a-good-mysql-index-part-2-cardinality/).

Comment: I have this doubt, this blog http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/do-you-always-need-index-on-where-column/ and many similar says it depends on how many rows that where clause can yield in. But some say records returned by the query shouldn't matter at all and only cardinality matters. My question is, is indexing dependent on rows returned or is it just dependent on cardinality(= how many different unique values that field has) ?

Comment: Indexing yields performance depending on cardinality. Closer to 1, the better. That's it. 10 possible values, 10 rows in the db = cardinality *can* be 1. Add 30k rows, cardinality is now 10/30k. It has nothing to do with "rows returned".

Comment: @N.B. thats what you say, but not the links all over. See this link http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/do-you-always-need-index-on-where-column/ or this http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/06/02/indexes-in-mysql/

Comment: As mentioned in the article you mentioned, the index slow down your query or speed it up; depending on the distribution of values. I suggest that you experiment yourself and see if the index helps or not.

Comment: Salman, as said in the question, right now the speeds are almost similar with no winner. That's 'cos I have only that many rows. I was trying to get the theory behind it.

Comment: I checked with some dummy data and failed to notice any improvements with the index. Will delete my answer in few minutes.

Comment: why delete, this explains the situation well!

Comment: @nawfal - the link you provided just confirms what I said. If index cardinality is below 0.2, mysql prefers table scan because it's faster. The problem occurs when mysql does the wrong cardinality estimation. This is something you can't always prevent from happening, that's why there are DBAs and monitoring software to tell you that there's a slow query and to fix it. General rule would be - the higher *possible* uniqueness, the better candidate for index that column is.

Comment: @N.B. `cardinality = COUNT(DISTINCT(field))/COUNT(*)`, while it is true that higher the cardinality better the indexing, the two links I provided doesn't talk anything on cardinality. It talks about `COUNT(*) WHERE field = 'xyz'/COUNT(*)` which they call it as selectivity. It reaches a conclusion if selectivity is lower than say 25%, it makes a good case for indexing. A lot of threads I read deals with selectivity and not cardinality, though cardinality and selectivity are closely related. Can you back your point with some link?

Comment: @SalmanA MySQL heuristics can be not that good. Catch the link here http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/06/02/indexes-in-mysql/. Read Oracle does a good job in handling that.